# scrollIntoView(true) is not scrolling to top, because of 'scrollable ancestor'. How do I get my element to be at the top of the view screen?

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

The docs say .scrollIntoView(true):

```
true - the top of the element will be aligned to the top of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor
[...]
Note: Depending on the layout of other elements, some elements may not be scrolled completely to the top or to the bottom.
```

ok, well how to I get it to scroll to the top, actually?  I want my element to be the first visible thing, in the viewport.

Comment: Have you actually tried using it? `.scrollIntoView(true)` works for most cases.

Comment: Oh, wait... try using it?? well, no I havent.  Geewiz, what an idea.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using it, wtf you think I'm in here asking?

Comment: Then, explain how it does not work for you. Provide a [mre]. It is not, in fact, at all clear what you are asking as you have not provided any details for your specific case.

Comment: I was quite clear and specific.  How to implement scroll into view that actually scrolls the element to the top of the viewport?  You're obv invested in my question not being clear and specific, so you're done here, now.

Comment: Instead of adamantly insisting that it's clear, add enough details for your question to be answerable. You have provided no code that shows the issue you are having with `scrollIntoView`; you cannot expect people to guess what your issue is when you have not shown neither your HTML structure, nor how you are calling the function. `scrollIntoView` works fine as shown here (https://jsfiddle.net/w1fk538h/)—if it does not work for your specific case, then provide a [mre] so others can help.

Comment: "Note: Depending on the layout of other elements, some elements may not be scrolled completely to the top or to the bottom."  So, you see, if you rtfm, it doesnt work fine. If there was something like scrollIntoView(magicaltricktoactuallywork) I think they'd say that in the fm.  Quite obv, 'other elements' are fing this up.  I'm not changing the other elements.  Probly jquery animate scrollTop is part of the answer.

Comment: Reread my comment: "if it does not work for your specific case, then provide a [mre] so others can help." You have not provided any code that shows the problem; you cannot expect people to guess at the actual issue with your code to help you fix it. The answer will depend on your current code.

Comment: since i'm not going to be changing the other 'other elements', a fiddle isnt going to do anything.  In that case, the answer would be 'change the containing div' or 'get rid of the grid thing' or sth like that.  scrollIntoView() simply does not work, in every circumstance, as described in the fm.

Comment: There can be other ways of calculating the position to scroll to without changing your HTML, but it depends on your HTML structure. If you are looking for answers on how to fix your code, then it is expected that you post a minimal, reproducible example. On the other hand, if you are only asking if there is an option that makes it always scroll to the top, then clearly state it in the question (although you can also figure it out by reading the documentation, which you may already have done, or the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollintoview)).